# Arraylist of number in textfield

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

That's the error i get when trying to execute my program. Honestly i really dont know where to start my code. 
i have a button name old and new.
i want the textfieldMemberID to display yearToday and an array of members who joined the organization. example if i click new, textfieldMemberId value will automatically display  "2012-000001" and if ic lick again new then it will display "2012-000002".
'
         i have a Member Class :

```
     import java.text.DecimalFormat;
     import java.text.NumberFormat;
     import java.util.ArrayList;
     import java.util.Calendar;
     import java.util.Date;


      public class Member {
      private ArrayList accounts;
      private String MemberId;
      private String VotersId;
private String FirstName;
private String MiddleName;
private String LastName;
private String LotNo;
private String Street;
private String Barangay;
private String City;
private String Region;
private int Age;
private String Gender;
private Date Birthday;
private String ContactNo;
private String EmailAddress;
private int size=0;
private int yearToday = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);

public Member(String MemberId) {
   NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("000000");
    size= this.accounts.size()+1;
    this.setMemberId(""+yearToday + "-" + (formatter.format(size)));  
} //im trying to have the solution here

public Member(String MemberId,String FirstName,String MiddleName,String LastName){
    this.setMemberId(MemberId);
    this.setFirstName(FirstName);
    this.setMiddleName(MiddleName);
    this.setLastName(LastName);
}


public int getAge() {
    return Age;
}

public void setAge(int Age) {
    this.Age = Age;
}

public String getBarangay() {
    return Barangay;
}

public void setBarangay(String Barangay) {
    this.Barangay = Barangay;
}

public Date getBirthday() {
    return Birthday;
}

public void setBirthday(Date Birthday) {
    this.Birthday = Birthday;
}

public String getCity() {
    return City;
}

public void setCity(String City) {
    this.City = City;
}

public String getContactNo() {
    return ContactNo;
}

public void setContactNo(String ContactNo) {
    this.ContactNo = ContactNo;
}

public String getEmailAddress() {
    return EmailAddress;
}

public void setEmailAddress(String EmailAddress) {
    this.EmailAddress = EmailAddress;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return FirstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String FirstName) {
    this.FirstName = FirstName;
}

public String getGender() {
    return Gender;
}

public void setGender(String Gender) {
    this.Gender = Gender;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return LastName;
}

public void setLastName(String LastName) {
    this.LastName = LastName;
}

public String getLotNo() {
    return LotNo;
}

public void setLotNo(String LotNo) {
    this.LotNo = LotNo;
}

public String getMemberId() {
    return MemberId;
}

public void setMemberId(String MemberId) {
    this.MemberId = MemberId;
}

public String getMiddleName() {
    return MiddleName;
}

public void setMiddleName(String MiddleName) {
    this.MiddleName = MiddleName;
}

public String getRegion() {
    return Region;
}

public void setRegion(String Region) {
    this.Region = Region;
}

public String getStreet() {
    return Street;
}

public void setStreet(String Street) {
    this.Street = Street;
}

public String getVotersId() {
    return VotersId;
}

public void setVotersId(String VotersId) {
    this.VotersId = VotersId;
}

public ArrayList getAccounts() {
    return accounts;
}

public void setAccounts(ArrayList accounts) {
    this.accounts = accounts;
}


@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Member other = (Member) obj;
    if ((this.MemberId == null) ? (other.MemberId != null) : !this.MemberId.equals(other.MemberId)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 5;
    hash = 89 * hash + (this.MemberId != null ? this.MemberId.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Member{" + "MemberId=" + MemberId + ", VotersId=" + VotersId + ", FirstName=" + FirstName + ", MiddleName=" + MiddleName + ", LastName=" + LastName + ", LotNo=" + LotNo + ", Street=" + Street + ", Barangay=" + Barangay + ", City=" + City + ", Region=" + Region + ", Age=" + Age + ", Gender=" + Gender + ", Birthday=" + Birthday + ", ContactNo=" + ContactNo + ", EmailAddress=" + EmailAddress + '}';
}
}
```

im trying to call the getmemberId by this code in Button"New"

```
String last="";
last = member.getMemberId();
this.txtMembersID.setText((last));
```

but i got this error.
    **Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException**
pls help. thank u.

Comment: Which line of code throw the `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that focuses on the problem without the dozen other fields.

Answer (score 3):

The issue occurs on this line of your first constructor:

```
size= this.accounts.size()+1;
```

Because `accounts` has not been initialized yet.

Adding this line before it:

```
accounts = new ArrayList();
```

Should fix your problem.

---

Also, for future reference, one of the most helpful pieces of information you can provide here would be the number of the line causing the exception- makes things a lot easier to solve!

Comment: i got the same error. Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: You added the line *before* `size= this.accounts.size()+1;`? And if so, on which line is your `NullPointerException` occurring, then?

Comment: yes i added it.                                                  String last="";
last = member.getMemberId();// I think in this line, it gives me a null value here 
this.txtMembersID.setText((last));                               this is my code in my AddMemberView in my buttonNew. im getting the memberId from Member Class

Comment: Where are you creating the member object?

Comment: you mean compiler? netbeans.

Comment: April, @xagyg is referring to the line of code in which you create the object `member`; something like `Member member = new Member(/* Some Parameters */)`.

Comment: **this is just what i have in my AddMemberView**                     'public class AddMemberView extends javax.swing.JPanel {

   private MainFrameView mainFrameView;
  private Member member;
    /**
     * Creates new form NewJPanel
     */
    public AddMemberView() {
        initComponents();
    }
    
      public AddMemberView(MainFrameView mf) {
        this.mainFrameView = mf;
        initComponents();
    }
      
        public AddMemberView(Member m) {
        this.member = m;
        initComponents();
    }'

Comment: Sorry, I can't see where you create a new Member object and assign it to the member variable so you can call member.getMemberId().